# How do I work with value returned by indexOf of an string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something only with the value returned by a conditional

```
{{#each maindata-hold.[2].qa}}
    <div class="section">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="person-link" id="{{id}}">
            <span class="name-role" id="{{id}}">
                {{name}} <br> {{role}}
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

all I need its to go over this part of the html and get the value of one of the nodes which contains the value "QA Manager", I am doing it like this

```
if ($('.person-link').text().toLowerCase().indexOf('qa m') > -1) {            
    $('.person-link').css('backgroundColor', 'black');
}
```

but with this way at the end all the nodes get a black background, I need black only the one for the QA Manager, any suggestion?

Comment: You need to do an each loop.   There are multiple classes with that name, so when your conditional becomes true, it sets all elements with the class `person-link` to black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is a good option:

```
$('.person-link').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('qa m') > -1;
}).css('backgroundColor', 'black');
```

```js
$('.person-link').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('qa m') > -1;
}).css({'background': '#0095ff', 'color': '#fff'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="person-link">Project Manager</div>
<div class="person-link">QA Manager</div>
<div class="person-link">Request Manager</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
$('.person-link:contains("qa m")').css('background-color', 'red');
```

---

Edit (Thanks to [skobaljik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386703/skobaljic)): Note that this method is case sensitive. To make it work in the above case you need to extend jQuery [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36166077).

Comment: This has to be correct answer, just what jQuery has to do. The only problem is: this selector is case sensitive, so he would have to extend jQuery [this way](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it with the helper function of [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

```js
$('.person-link').css("backgroundColor", function(_,_css){
   return this.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf('qa m') > -1 ? "black" : _css;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="person-link">Project Manager</div>
<div class="person-link" style="color:white">QA Manager</div>
<div class="person-link">Request Manager</div>
```

Comment: ummm what is _,_ and  _css here ? I did not get it.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Thats just a variable. And that is the current `backgroundColor`

Comment: Does it mean, besides the loop, which is necessary, it would also get current background color (and use more resources)?

Comment: @skobaljic See the other answer which uses `.filter()`, that would iterate twice, one time for filtering and other for setting css. But here in my code, only one iteration will happen. I believe a single variable is not a matter before  a whole iteration. :)

Comment: It is true, but it is also true that guys from jQuery team have already created `:contains` selector (please check that answer).

Comment: @skobaljic Yeah that has to be the best answer here in this context.

Comment: I have never used this helper function for css - I've learned something new, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like:

```
$(".person-link").each(function(){
  var $item = $(this);
  if ( $item.text().toLowerCase().indexOf('qa m') > -1){
    $item.css('backgroundColor', 'black');
  }
});
```

that way it will check each index and if it matches, change that individual css, and not all matching classes.